# Eval Inside Of Funtion Results In Error, While Outside It Does Not

Tags: python, eval

I wrote a small python script that takes in descriptions of simple impedance networks and calculates the effective impedance. The code is pastebined [here](http://pastebin.com/wEepuqkn). The code, as is, runs correctly, but if you sub in the commented out lines that are below them, which simply moves the eval to the zcalc function, the code does not work. It throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I have tested a couple simple functions that have `return eval(equ)` in them using simple cases like `4+2` and even `parallel([5j,5j])` and `parallel([5j,parallel([5j,5j])])` and they work. I'm not sure why the error is occurring when it does not in every other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of `zcalc`, `parallel` is a function. Inside of `zcalc`, `parallel` is a list. Calling `eval` inside `zcalc`, it will attempt to access the list instead of the function. Consider changing the name of one of them, so there is no ambiguity. Ex.

```
def zcalc(equ):
        equ = filter(equ)
        pos = equ.find('|')
        while pos != -1:
                parallel_seq = []
                temp_pos = pos
                while True:     #gather all scopes to the left into list
                        lpos = leftscope(equ, temp_pos)
                        parallel_seq.insert(0, equ[lpos:temp_pos])
                        if (lpos == 0): break
                        elif (equ[lpos-1] != "|"): break
                        temp_pos = lpos-1
                temp_pos = pos
                while True:     #gather all scope to the right into list
                        rpos = rightscope(equ, temp_pos)
                        parallel_seq.append(equ[temp_pos+1:rpos+1])
                        if (rpos == len(equ)-1) or (equ[rpos+1] != "|"): break
                        temp_pos = rpos+1
                new_equ = "parallel(["
                for i in parallel_seq:      #create string for paralleled function
                        new_equ = new_equ + i + ","
                equ = equ[0:lpos] + new_equ[:len(new_equ)-1] + "])" + equ[rpos+1:]      #replace parallelized part of string with parallel string
                pos = equ.find("|")
        #return equ
        return eval(equ)
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I didn't see that. It works.